# How to Solve error: This app can't be activated by the Built-in Administrator in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

when iam enabled my built-in administrator account iam getting a error that is This app can't be activated by the Built-in Administrator in Windows 8.1. Anybody know a solution for this error

Comment: Specific information is required. First what application are you trying to run exactly? Second it seems like you will need to use a different user other then the default Administrator.  Have you considered upgrading to Windows 8.1?

Comment: Have you tried Googling the error? Many links related to this error pops up in the results.

Answer (score 9):

It can be solved through editing a Group Policy, here the steps........

Open Local Group Policy Editor

- **Windows + R**
- Type **Gpedit.msc**

Go to the following Policy

- Windows Settings.
- Security Settings.
- Local Policies.
- Security Options.

Enable the Policy and reboot/logoff

**User Account Control:Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in- Administrator account.**

For more clarification visit http://feelsecured.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/how-to-solve-error-this-app-cant-be-activated-by-the-built-in-administrator-in-windows-8-1/

Comment: This does not change the fact you cannot link the built-in Administrator to a Microsoft Account which some Windows Store applications require.  But this does actually answer the author's question.

Comment: This error is showings, when we login as built in administrator we can't use the apps likes video player, picture viewer, Music player etc, if the author meant a solution for that it will definitely help him

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. The Store apps require UAC to be enabled. The buildin account doesn't have UAC, so you can't run the apps.